# How to create nested data structures Solidity 0.8

Tags: solidity, struct, solidity-0.8.x

I'm a JS dev fairly new to solidity. I couldn't find something to cover this when dealing with custom data. I want to create a function that I can use to push data into the contract. I'm trying to get nested data inside my contract but running into various errors each time I try something different, this is my most recent error.

"Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct DustContr.Trait storage ref[] storage ref."

Here's my code. Any help or links to a good document would be appreciated

```
contract DustContract is ERC721Enumerable, ReentrancyGuard, Ownable {

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    using Strings for uint256;
    uint256 public constant maxFux = 100;
    bool public contractIsActive;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    mapping (uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs;
    
    struct Funds {
        uint amount;
        address sender;
        uint time;
    }

    struct TraitData {
        uint256 id;
        string name;
        string svg;
    }

    struct Trait {
        TraitData[] common;
        TraitData[] uncommon;
        TraitData[] rare;
        TraitData[] epic;
        TraitData[] legendary;
    }
    
        struct Traits {
            Trait[] eyes;
            Trait[] body;
            Trait[] head;
        }
        
   Traits internal traits;
   Trait internal trait;
    TraitData internal traitData;
    
    function createTrait(
        uint256 _rarity,
        uint256 _traitType,
        uint256 _id,
        string calldata _name,
        string calldata _svg
        
    )
    external onlyOwner contractActive 
    {

        require(_traitType > 0);
        require(_rarity > 0);
        require(_id > 0);
        require(bytes(_name).length > 0);
        require(bytes(_svg).length > 0);

        trait.common.push(traits.eyes.push(TraitData(_id, _name, _svg)));

    }
```

This is the js version of what I'm trying to create

```
let Trait = {
        common:{
            eyes: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}],
            body: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}],
            head: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}]
        },
        uncommon:{
            eyes: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}],
            body: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}],
            head: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}]
        },
        rare:{
            eyes: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}],
            body: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}],
            head: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}]
        },
        epic:{
            eyes: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}],
            body: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}],
            head: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}]
        },
        legendary:{
            eyes: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}],
            body: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}],
            head: [{"id":1,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"},{"id":2,"name":"name","svg":"<svg></svg>"}]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`traits.eyes.push(TraitData(_id, _name, _svg))` returns the new length of the array.

Since `trait.common` is of type `TraitData`, trying to push and integer fails and returns an error.

You might want to try (assuming you want to insert the same TraitData is `trait.common`).

```
uint idx = traits.eyes.push(TraitData(_id, _name, _svg)) - 1;
trait.common.push(traits.eyes[idx]);
```

Comment: Since solc 0.6 [push(data)](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/types.html#array-members) returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks but still getting the same error, just on the new line

Comment: I added more info around what I want the data structure to look like if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your nesting of structs is not quite right. If you want it to work like in your js example, you swap the contents of trait and traits, and remove the arrays on common, uncommon, ect. Like this:

```
    struct TraitData {
        uint256 ids
        string name;
        string svg;
    }

    struct Trait {
        TraitData[] eyes;
        TraitData[] body;
        TraitData[] head;
    }
    
    struct Traits {
        Trait common;
        Trait uncommon;
        Trait rare;
        Trait epic;
        Trait legendary;
        }
```

Side note your struct names make this kind of confusing and I would consider renaming them to clarify what they're doing in your mind

Also, you only declare a storage variable of your top level struct for storage.
Right now you have

```
Traits internal traits;
Trait internal trait;
TraitData internal traitData;`
```

and you want

```
Traits internal traits;
```

Also, the syntax of adding a new element onto the datastructure might be more like

```
traits.common.eyes.push(TraitData(_id, _name, _svg);
```

Also as a side not on nft traits, typically theyre not stored inside the smart contract unless you need to make on chain decisions with them, since it takes a lot of gas/storage to put them all on chain.

People typically store a link to ipfs where the metadata for the nfts is stored. This is what interoperates with opensea ect.

If you do want to get trait data on chain, a much more effecient way of doing so would be to use a merkle tree, and have users submit a merkle proof describing which traits their nft has that can be checked against a merkle root stored in the contract.

See https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_nft_contract/blob/main/contract/SimpleNft.sol

and

https://soliditydeveloper.com/merkle-tree